# Hibernate AttributeConverter with null database value

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am writing Attribute converter to convert a model into its JSON String while storing to database and converting JSON string back to model while reading from database.
It is working fine when it has data.

Well, the model holds a collection. When the collection is empty, which is what it gets initialized to by default, on writing to db I need to write `null` instead of something like `{ values : {} }`. This works fine.
While reading from db though I am checking if db content is null, then I want that field in entity to have instance of model with empty collection.

```
    public class MyWarningsJsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyWarnings, String> {

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final MyWarnings warnings) {
            if ( null != warnings && (!warnings.isEmpty()) ) {
                return JSON_CONVERTED_WARNINGS;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public MyWarnings convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {

            if (null != dbData) {
                return MODEL_FROM_JSON_OF_DBDATA;
            }
            //this executes. But gets overridden by hibernate to null 
            return MyWarnings.createNew();
        }
    }
```

Entity has model like

```
    @Column(name = "warnings")
    @Convert(converter = MyWarningsJsonConverter.class)
    private MyWarnings warnings = MyWarnings.createNew();
```

The problem seems to be in `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract`. This code returns null if resultset content is null.

```
    if ( value == null || rs.wasNull() ) {  //rs resultset
        return null;
    }
```

So, on reading row with null for warnings I want entity to have instance of MyWarnings with empty collections but I am getting null. How can I do that ?

Comment: What particular version of Hibernate?

Comment: I find it easier to have a the converted object field be `@Transient` and use `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` and `@PostLoad` to convert it from a String value is much easier than dealing with AttributeConverters.

Comment: Hibernate version 4.3.7